# Installed Ubuntu on an external Harddisk , but can not use my Wlan0 now

Tags: networking

I installed Ubuntu on a external Hard-disk , but after that I can not enter on my Wlan0 anymore

Notebook info-way w7415 and it is not more possible too activate and deactivate Wlan0 wireless with the FN- Wireless contact button

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.